# How to remove Traces of Previous Ubuntu Installation?

Tags: user-management

I had to reinstall my Ubuntu 13.04 due to a GUI-crashing experiment with cairo-deck. Actually I often tamper with GUI, and from time to time it leads to the necessity of re-installation. 
I re-install the system on / but I leave /Home intact to preserve my files. /Home seems to contain some settings from previous installations. Can anyone help me clear those settings?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration files are kept in files and directories starting with `.` (dot) in their name, hence you only have to move the files to another directory then restart your session. With simply opening a terminal then executing:

```
mv ~/.* ~/config.bk/`
```

After this restart or close your session and next time your configurations will be recreated with the defaults. **Remember that this also remove other configurations and personalizations that where applied after your reinstalled your system**, so you will need to reconfigure everything again.